# Kendo Ui Grid column template with kendo window pop up in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to Angular JS and Kendo UI. I am trying to open an pop up window from Kendo UI grid column template.
The grid is in AngularJs directive.

1. How to call js function within the template :
   When I define as this

`<a href='javascript:changeShow()' class='link'>#=dataType#</a>`

I get function not found. 
My function is defined in directive controller scope.

```
var changeShow = function() {
    console.log('changeShow');
 };
```

2. How to open a pop up window from this fucntion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question but I'm assuming you wish to call a function from inside your custom template definition.

For example:

```
 "#= <a ng-click="openTheWindow()">Click to open the window</a> #"
```

The scope that the template runs in is not the angular scope that your widget is in (unfortunately).

1. If you put the function you want to call from your template into global space the template will be able to call it. Obviously this doesn't deliver the desired encapsulation and pollutes the global namespace.
   I implemented a utility closure in global scope for all the custom formatting functions I wanted to use in my templates and referenced them there.
2. The reference to your Kendo window is added to your directive's scope like so:

   `<kendo-window="myWindowReference">`

   Because this reference is in the directive's scope you need 
   to fetch the scope by making an external request to the angular framework from your globally accessible utility function. That would go a something like this:

   `var angularScope = angular.$injector.get('nameOfDirective').scope();`

   Then open the window like this:

   `angularScope.myWindowReference.open();`

   (The above syntax is off the top of my head but should point you in the correct direction).

I'm sorry that I can't offer a cleaner solution but Kendo Angular has its quirks and I don't claim to understand them all perfectly. This approach provided us with a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Scope is a challenge in Angular. this helps me

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If I addressed your issue with this answer you could mark the answer correct. If it was truely helpful maybe an upvote is in order 